# Teradata syntax for Xml codes

Tags: syntax, teradata

Please provide teradata syntax for the below scenario:

1. get the valid values from xml tags apart from nulls in column 1.
2. get the name of the tags where value is available in column 2

For example:refer the below xml code.

***Column 1***
**55: MENS DENIM**
**10k**

***Column 2***
**Department**

**Major**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Filters><Filter><Max/><Joiners/><Department>55: MENS DENIM</Department>
 <Major>10</Major><Sub/><Min/></Filter></Filters>
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your Teradata Version you might want to check the [Teradata XML Services](http://downloads.teradata.com/download/extensibility/teradata-xml-services)

In the new Version 14.10 I've seen, that they created a more elegant UDF for that, which decides by the size of the XML if XPath syntax is possible or not. But haven't tried that yet.